# ¿Cómo puedo hacer efectivo el envío de un mensaje al email a través de un formulario en HTML5?

Tags: html5, formularios, email, response

Tengo un formulario sencillo en _HTML5, y necesito saber cómo puedo hacerlo efectivo para que el usuario final pueda enviar su mensaje a mi correo electrónico usando este mismo formulario.

Preferiblemente en PHP. Saludos y buen día.

Código:

```
<form name="sentMessage" id="contactForm" class="form" novalidate>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-6 form-group">
      <input type="text" id="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Nombre" required="required">
      <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-6 form-group">
      <input type="email" id="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" required="required">
      <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <textarea name="message" id="message" class="form-control" rows="5" placeholder="Escriba su comentario o sugerencia." required></textarea>
    <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
  </div>
  <div id="success"></div>
  <button class="btn btn btn-lg" type="submit">Enviar Mensaje</button>
</form>
```

Agradezco de antemano por sus respuestas y códigos.

Sin más por el momento, eso es todo. Saludos cordiales y buen día.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sin usar, por ejemplo `PHP`, sería de la siguiente manera la más fácil:

```
<form action="mailto:mi@email.com" enctype="text/plain" name="sentMessage"  id="contactForm" class="form" novalidate>

   <!-- Resto de código -->    
</form>
```

---

[FORMSPREE.IO](https://github.com/formspree/formspree), el cual envías a ellos el email y ellos te lo reenvían a tu email:

```
<form action="https://formspree.io/mi@email.com">
    <input type="text" name="name">
    <input type="email" name="_replyto">
    <input type="submit" value="Send">
</form>
```

---

Y por último usando `PHP` la forma más simple sería:

**enviar.php**:

```
<?php
$to      = 'mi@email.com';
$subject = 'Mi formulario';

$name    = $_POST['name'];     // name="name"
$email   = $_POST['email'];    // name="email"
$message = $_POST['message'];  // name="message"

// Aquí compones el cuerpo del mail
$bodyMail  = "Haz recibido un email de {$name}".PHP_EOL;
$bodyMail .= "El mensaje es:".PHP_EOL;
$bodyMail .= $message;

// Configurar Content-type
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0'.PHP_EOL;
$headers .= 'Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8'.PHP_EOL;

// Enviado desde el email del usuario
$headers .= 'From: '.$email.PHP_EOL;

// Adicional
$headers .= 'Cc:   <ejemplo@email.com>'.PHP_EOL;
$headers .= 'Bcc:  <ejemplo@email.com>'.PHP_EOL;

// Enviar email
if ( mail($to, $subject, $bodyMail, $headers) ) {

    $mensaje = 'Email se ha enviado con éxito.';
}
else {

    $mensaje = 'Fallo al enviar el Email.';
}
```

Puedes hacer algunas validaciones en el fichero de `PHP` si deseas, no lo he incluido por simplificar.

En el formulario `HTML` tienes que apuntar al fichero `enviar.php` y añadir algunos atributos que te faltan para poder recibir lo por el método `POST` en este caso:

```
<-- incluimos los atributos action y method -->
<form action="enviar.php" method="post" name="sentMessage"  id="contactForm" class="form" novalidate>     

      <-- incluimos el atributo name -->
      <input type="text" id="name" name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Nombre" required="required">

      ....

      <-- incluimos el atributo name -->
      <input type="email" id="email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" required="required">

    ....

    <textarea name="message" id="message" class="form-control" rows="5" placeholder="Escriba su comentario o sugerencia." required></textarea>        
    ....
</form>
```

Si lo quieres más avanzado te recomiendo [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer)

Comment: Ok. Lo voy a intentar hacer así, por PHP, a ver qué pasa. Saludos y gracias.

Comment: Funcionó mejor por PHP. Por localhost no funcionaba por algo que restringía el XAMPP, pero vía web, ya funciona. Ahora ya sólo faltaría darle cuerpo al mensaje. Enhorabuena, gracias por el código. Saludos.